# Как снять\обновить задачу asyncio

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, asyncio, schedule

```py
async def send_schedule_message():
    if sch_message_obj.get_is_on():
       await bot.send_message(sch_message_obj.get_chat_id(), sch_message_obj.text)
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every(sch_message_obj.get_minutes()).minutes.do(send_schedule_message)
    while sch_message_obj.is_on:
       await aioschedule.run_pending()
       await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())
```

Мне необходимо отправлять сообщение в тг с некоторым интервалом. Нужно чтобы была возможность этот интервал менять. Не могу разобраться, как изменить время с которым aioscheduler отправляет сообщение. Можно ли как то выключить таск и запустить по новой но с новым временем? Подскажите пожалуйста

В sch_message_obj находятся chat_id, text сообщения, время в минутах и флаг False\True (уточнение)

Answer (score 0):

Итак, моё решение:

```py
import time

async def sch():
    last=time.time()
    while True:
        now=time.time()
        if now-last > sch_message_obj.get_minutes()*60:
            last=now
            if sch_message_obj.get_is_on():
                await bot.send_message(sch_message_obj.get_chat_id(), sch_message_obj.text)

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(sch())
```